# Display div elements based on leaflet js base map selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have various baselayers on my leaflet map. I've also created div elements that correspond to each of those layers. I need to show and hide those div elements based on which baselayer is actually in use. I do not want all the div elements on the page simulatenously.

I've tried to use jQuery .show() & .hide() & .toggle() but haven't been able to get these to work. I need my .cuomoinfo & .nixoninfo to be hidden by default and then show based on which baselayer is in use.

```
var baselayers = {
    "Andrew Cuomo Votes": CuomoLayer,
    "Cynthia Nixon Votes": NixonLayer,
    "Total Votes Cast": totalvotecountlayer,
  };

var overlays = {
  "NYS Assembly Districts": AssemblyOverlay,
  "NYC Council Districts": CouncilOverlay,
};

L.control.layers(baselayers, overlays).addTo(mymap);

// creating a custom div that changes the ed information within it based on mouseover
var cuomoinfo = L.control();

  cuomoinfo.onAdd = function (cuomomap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'cuomoinfo'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
  };

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
  cuomoinfo.update = function (cuomoprops) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Votes for Andrew M. Cuomo</h4>' +  (cuomoprops ?
        '<b>' + cuomoprops.ElectDist + '</b><br/>' + cuomoprops.QueensCountyGovernorDemocraticPrimarySept2018_Cuomo + ' votes cast'
        : 'Hover over an Electrion District to see voting results');
  };

cuomoinfo.addTo(mymap);

$('.cuomoinfo').hide()
```

Comment: You create a control for your div. Do you absolutely need to display it on your map ? (would not it be better outside ?)

Comment: Yes, it should be displayed on top of the map. It contains information on mouseover events pertaining to the map.